# Accessing Guests of multiple Qemu-kvm instances via libvirt or qmp

Tags: qemu

Scenario:

In a container context , I am trying to spawn multiple "qemu-system-" commands,each of which provides me  one Ubuntu guests ( lets say 10 of them to be precise ), I wanted to install packages in the each of the instances and push my code there and run

Q1. How can one access each of these 10 Qemu-kvm instances via single libvirt library installed ( virsh). Can you provide an  example connecting to say 2 qemu-kvm guests.?
Q2. How can one install packages ( eg. do an apt install) to each of these qemu-kvm guest instances from the hosting container.
Q3. I want to have these guests communicate ( both directions) independently to the hostsystem via seperate ip. what network technolgy option is recommended for back and forth communicatio with host . Is it bridging still or something better?